# Regex for splitting a string containing text and url

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have input strings like below:

```
[URL=http://...]Lorem ipsum[/URL]
```

They should be converted in HTML tags:

```
<a href="http://...">Lorem ipsum</a>
```

Example:

```
[URL=http://domain.com]My Awesome Link Text[/URL]
```

This should be converted in:

```
<a href="http://domain.com">My Awesome Link Text</a>
```

---

I tried to split the string using a regular expression:

```
> a = "[URL=http://domain.com]My Awesome Link Text[/URL]"
'[URL=http://domain.com]My Awesome Link Text[/URL]'
> s = a.split(/\[|\]|=/)
[ '',
  'URL',
  'http://domain.com',
  'My Awesome Link Text',
  '/URL',
  '' ]
> o = "<a href=\"" + s[2] + "\">" + s[3] + "</a>"
'<a href="http://domain.com">My Awesome Link Text</a>'
```

This works fine for links that don't contain `=` in their url. But things get complicated when we have querystring parameters:

```
> a = "[URL=http://domain.com?param=value]My Awesome Link Text[/URL]"
'[URL=http://domain.com?param=value]My Awesome Link Text[/URL]'
> s = a.split(/\[|\]|=/)
[ '',
  'URL',
  'http://domain.com?param',
  'value',
  'My Awesome Link Text',
  '/URL',
  '' ]
> o = "<a href=\"" + s[2] + "\">" + s[3] + "</a>"
'<a href="http://domain.com?param">value</a>'
```

How to split such strings, but not splitting the `=` inside of the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern:

```
^.*?\[URL=([^\]]*)\]([^\[]*).*$
```

Replacement:

```
<a href="$1">$2</a>
```

In JavaScript:

```
> "[URL=http://domain.com?asd=a]My Awesome Link Text[/URL]".replace(/^.*?\[URL=([^\]]*)\]([^\[]*).*$/, '<a href="$1">$2</a>')
'<a href="http://domain.com?asd=a">My Awesome Link Text</a>'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/34)

Answer (score 1):

Don't split, just parse it!

```
a.match(/\[URL=(.+)\](.+)\[\/URL\]/i)
```

And we get:

```
["[URL=http://domain.com]My Awesome Link Text[/URL]", "http://domain.com", "My Awesome Link Text"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Javascript.

`[URL=([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)\[\/URL\]`

Not splitting : decomposing into groups.

```
t = '[URL=http://domain.com?param=value]My Awesome Link Text[/URL]'
r = /\[URL=([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)\[\/URL\]/;
t.match(r)
--> ["[URL=http://domain.com?param=value]My Awesome Link Text[/URL]", "http://domain.com?param=value", "My Awesome Link Text"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var reg = /\[URL\=([^\]]+)\](.*)\[\/URL\]$/;
var str = '[URL=http://domain.com]My Awesome Link Text[/URL]';
var result = str.match(reg);
```

the result val:

```
["[URL=http://domain.com]My Awesome Link Text[/URL]", "http://domain.com", "My Awesome Link Text"]
```

you can use the result:

```
var html = "<a href=\"" + result[1] + "\">" + result[2] + "</a>";
```

other sample test:

maybe the link text include `[]` or other tag `[red][/red]` ,like this

```
"[URL=http://domain.com]My Awesome [red]Link Text[/red][/URL]"
```

so the first answer is not the best choice,because it not allow the link text include`[`or`]`